# Regex for matching lemmy spoiler tags

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write regex (JS flavor) that matches spoilers in text.

```
// this should match with group title = "title of the spoiler" and body = "content"
// and it's only one working for now :/

::: spoiler title of the spoiler
content
:::

// this should match

::: spoiler title
content
on multiple
lines

**with some style**
:::

// this should match

::: spoiler title
body
containing
colon:
:::
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
:::\sspoiler\s+(?<title>.+)\n(?<body>.+)\n:::
```

However it doesn't match spoilers containing newlines, only first example is working.

[link](https://regex101.com/r/ILypPy/2) to regex101.com

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to get correct matches:

```bash
:::\s+spoiler\s+(?<title>.+)\n(?<body>.(?:.*\n)+?):::
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ILypPy/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `:::`: Match starting `:::`
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `spoiler`: Match text `spoiler`
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<title>.+)`: Match 1+ of any character in capture group named `title`
- `\n`: Match a line break
- `(?<body>.`: capture group named `body` that starts with a character

  - `(?:.*\n)+?`: Match 0 or of any character followed by a line break and repeat this group 1+ times (lazy)
- `)`:
- `:::` Match ending `:::`

Answer (score 0):

You could assert that after matching a single non whitespace char for the title, the next lines do not have only whitespace chars until matching `:::` at the start of a line.

```
:::\sspoiler\s+(?<title>\S.*)\n(?!\s*^:::)(?<body>(?:.*\n)+?):::
```

**Explanation**

- `:::` Match literally (Or use `^:::` if it has to be at the start of the string)
- `\sspoiler\s+` Match a whitespace char, then `spoiler` followed by 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?<title>\S.*)` Named group *title*, match a single non whitespace char and then the rest of the line
- `\n(?!\s*^:::)` Match a newline, and assert not only whitespace chars until `:::` at the start of a line
- `(?<body>(?:.*\n)+?)` Named group *body*, repeat matching all lines, as few as possible
- `:::` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ij68y9/1)

Or for JavaScript, where `[^]` matches any character including a newline:

```
:::\sspoiler\s+(?<title>\S.*)\n(?!\s*^:::)(?<body>[^]*?)\n:::
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qb16LN/1)

**Note** that `\s` can also match a newline